# Running data from parent table with condition on child table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The parent table is storing the latest update time for machine2 and machine3, but the updates themselves are stored in the child table, and I would like to return the latest update time for each machine that is a check.

I can join the two, but I don't know how to state the condition, because I want to return other data which is in the parent table (e.g. tester)

**Parent table**

| id (PK) | time | title | tester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23:50 | machine2 | tester X |
| 3 | 18:40 | machine3 | tester Y |

**Child table**

| id | time | notes | Parent_entry (FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23:50 | test | 2 |
| 2 | 20:50 | check | 2 |
| 3 | 19:20 | check | 2 |
| 4 | 18:40 | test | 3 |
| 5 | 14:30 | check | 3 |

**Result needed**

| time | title | tester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20:50 | machine2 | tester X |
| 14:30 | machine3 | tester Y |

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: . . Your desired results are just the results from the parent table.

Comment: I want the update time from the child table of the latest check. The parent table will overwrite that with the latest update, which I can't tell whether it is a check or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want the child that has the latest `'check'` row:

```
select p.*, c.*
from parent p left join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parent_entry order by time desc) as seqnum
      from children c
      where notes = 'check'
     ) c
     on c.parent_entry = p.id and c.seqnum = 1;
```