# Joining on one record before the current one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table lists the assignees for a certain task. There can be only one at a time, and it can be a group or a user, each of them belonging to an entity. When a new row is entered, it means the assignee has changed.

I am trying to show the transfers from and to a new assignee. In the example below, the earliest transfer was on 16-07-2021, when the assignee changed from group 44 of entity 4444 to user 333 from entity 3333 (concatenating them as below will do).

| ID | timestamp | group | user | entity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21-07-2021 | 11 | NULL | 1111 |
| 2 | 20-07-2021 | 22 | NULL | 2222 |
| 3 | 16-07-2021 | NULL | 333 | 3333 |
| 4 | 14-07-2021 | 44 | NULL | 4444 |

Expected

| ID | timestamp | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21-07-2021 | 22_2222 | 11_1111 |
| 2 | 20-07-2021 | 333_3333 | 22_2222 |
| 3 | 16-07-2021 | 44_4444 | 333_3333 |

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Studio 2018 for this.

Comment: There is no "SQL Server Studio 2018". If you mean SQL Server Management Studio, the current version is 18, not 2018. If you mean SQL Server, there is no 2018 at all. The current version is 2019, and the one prior was 2017.

Comment: Saying "Studio 2018" is like telling someone the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dash radio. It'd be fine in a regular person, but no so much for someone aspiring to work on cars for a living.

Comment: Do find [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and/or LAG in the documentation, and try to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to construct the "from" and "to" strings.  That looks like:

```
select t.id, t.timestamp, prev_egu as from_egu, egu as to_egu 
from (select t.*, v.egu,
             lag(v.egu) over (order by timestamp) as prev_egu
      from t cross apply
           (values (concat(entity, '_', coalesce(group, user))(
           ) v(egu)
     ) t
where prev_egu is not null;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Gordon. You have also solved this one for me before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214115/running-data-from-parent-table-with-condition-on-child-table-sql-server

Comment: Since you are an author, would you be able to recommend me a book on these kind of queries? These are most likely around Data Analysis on SQL, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @joe . . . Precisely because I am an author, I would recommend my books on that subject.  However, Stack Overflow is not a place to recommend books.